# Faster Way To Find Factors of n only using the math library

Tags: python, performance, math, python-3.7, factorization

Before you mark this as a duplicate...

I need to find the all the factors of n (which there are tons of solutions for). The fastest one I was able to implement was by looping through the range of 2 to sqrt of `n`. This is what I have thus far...

```
def get_factors(n):
    factors = set()
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.update([i, n // i])
    return factors
```

This is a very fast method for finding the factors of `n`, but I am wondering if there is a faster way to find the factors of `n`. The only restriction I have is that I can only use the math library in Python 3.7. Any ideas on how this can be done faster? I couldn't find answers that only used the math library. Is there anything I can do to improve the efficency of my current algorithm?

Comment: What is the magnitude of the numbers?

Comment: 18 bits is not very large. That gives you ints bounded by 262143

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. I meant 64 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Just like @John Coleman said in the comment of this solution, it's better to obtain the factors while you're calculating the primes, so you can avoid extra work in case you finish factorizing the number before the sieve is finished. The updated code would be:

```
def factors(number):
    n=int(number**.5)+1
    x=number
    divisors=[]
    era =[1] * n
    primes=[]
    for p in range(2, n):
        if era[p]:
            primes.append(p)
            while x%p==0:
                x//=p
                divisors.append(p)
            for i in range(p*p, n, p):
                era[i] = False
    if x!=1:
        divisors.append(x)    
    return divisors
```

**OG Solution:**

Get the prime factors between 2 and sqrt(n) with the [Erathostenes Sieve](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-sieve-of-eratosthenes/#:%7E:text=multiples%20of%20k-,Python%20Program%20for%20Sieve%20of%20Eratosthenes,than%20or%20equal%20to%20n.&text=For%20example%2C%20if%20n%20is,13%2C%2017%2C%2019%E2%80%9D.) and after it, check which ones are divisors of n. That will reduce hugely the running time of your code.

The Erathostenes sieve doesn't use more than lists, operations `%,>=,<=` and booleans.

Here's a shorter implementation than the one in the link I shared you:

```
def factors(number):
    n=int(number**.5)+1
    era =[1] * n
    primes=[]
    for p in range(2, n):
        if era[p]:
            primes.append(p)
            for i in range(p*p, n, p):
                era[i] = False
    divisors=[]
    x=number
    for i in primes:
        while x%i==0:
            x//=i
            divisors.append(i)
    if x!=1:
        divisors.append(x)    
    return divisors
```

Comment: Finding all primes below the square root seems inefficient. Once a prime is found that it is a divisor, use that right away to reduce the problem. Say `n = 2**40`, your algorithm would first find roughly 80,000 primes even though it only needs 1.

Comment: You're right, that's a better solution. Let me edit this for possible future users that find this solution.

Comment: @HasnainAli--1) factors doesn't produce the right answer.  For n = 32768, it results in `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]` rather than `{16384, 8192, 2, 4096, 4, 2048, 32, 1024, 8, 64, 128, 256, 16, 512}`.  2) Also,it's actually 2x slower for n = 32, 768 (using timeit).  I thought the goal was a faster algorithm that produced the same output or did I miss something?

Comment: @DarrylG Well, the goal is find the numbers (factors) that multiply to n. 2^15 is the prime factorization. Each of those numbers (I should probably sort my final set), can evenly be divided by n.

Comment: Sorry.I will add the part of the divisors. What you will get with this solution is the prime factors, and from that is also possible to get the divisors, but the code doesn't get you them.

Comment: @HasnainAli--just pointing out your posted solution seems to provide the correct answer (i.e. `{16384, 8192, 2, 4096, 4, 2048, 32, 1024, 8, 64, 128, 256, 16, 512}`--order doesn't matter), while your accepted answer provides a different answer which seems incorrect and slower.

Answer (score 2):

**Fastest Method to find all factors of a number**

Constraint--don't use any external libraries beyond math

Tested 4 methods

1. Trial Division (posted code by questioner @HasnainAli) aka Trial
2. Eratosthenes Sieve (from @MonsieurGalois post)  aka Sieve
3. Prime Factorization [Inspired by](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generating-all-divisors-of-a-number-using-its-prime-factorization/) aka Factorize
4. Primes based upon Wheel Factorization inspired by [Wheel Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) aka Wheel

**Results**

Results are relative to Trial Division i.e. (Trial Division time) ÷ (Other approach time)
[image: Relative Benchmarks]

Benchmarks using [Benchit](https://pypi.org/project/benchit/) by @Davakar which uses timeit

```
N            trial  sieve     prime_fac  wheel_fac                                           
1             1.0  1.070048   1.129752   1.104619
2             1.0  1.438679   3.201589   1.119284
4             1.0  1.492564   2.749838   1.176149
8             1.0  1.595604   3.164555   1.290554
16            1.0  1.707575   2.917286   1.172851
32            1.0  2.051244   3.070331   1.262998
64            1.0  1.982820   2.701439   1.073524
128           1.0  2.188541   2.776955   1.098292
256           1.0  2.086762   2.442863   0.945812
512           1.0  2.365761   2.446502   0.914936
1024          1.0  2.516539   2.076006   0.777048
2048          1.0  2.518634   1.878156   0.690900
4096          1.0  2.546800   1.585665   0.573352
8192          1.0  2.623528   1.351017   0.484521
16384         1.0  2.642640   1.117743   0.395437
32768         1.0  2.796339   0.920231   0.327264
65536         1.0  2.757787   0.725866   0.258145
131072        1.0  2.790135   0.529174   0.189576
262144        1.0  2.676348   0.374986   0.148726
524288        1.0  2.877928   0.269510   0.107237
1048576       1.0  2.522501   0.189929   0.080233
2097152       1.0  3.142147   0.125797   0.053157
4194304       1.0  2.673095   0.105293   0.045798
8388608       1.0  2.675686   0.075033   0.030105
16777216      1.0  2.508037   0.057209   0.022760
33554432      1.0  2.491193   0.038634   0.015440
67108864      1.0  2.485025   0.029142   0.011826
134217728     1.0  2.493403   0.021297   0.008597
268435456     1.0  2.492891   0.015538   0.006098
536870912     1.0  2.448088   0.011308   0.004539
1073741824    1.0  1.512157   0.005103   0.002075
```

Conclusion:

- Sieve method always slower than trial division (i.e. ratio column > 1)
- Trial division fastest up to n ~256
- Wheel factorization method fastest overall (i.e. 481X trial division for n = 2**30 i.e. 1/0.002075 ~ 481)

**Code**

Method 1: Original Post

```
import math

def trial(n):
  " Factors by trial division "
  factors = set()
  for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):
      if n % i == 0:
          factors.update([i, n // i])
  return factors
```

Method 2--Sieve (@MonsieurGalois post)

```
def factors_sieve(number):
  " Using primes in trial division "

  # Find primes up to sqrt(n)
  n=int(number**.5)+1
  era =[1] * n
  primes=[]
  for p in range(2, n):
      if era[p]:
          primes.append(p)
          for i in range(p*p, n, p):
              era[i] = False

  # Trial division using primes
  divisors=[]
  x=number
  for i in primes:
      while x%i==0:
          x//=i
          divisors.append(i)
  if x!=1:
      divisors.append(x)    
  return divisors
```

Method 3--Finding divisors based upon prime factorization

[Inspired by](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generating-all-divisors-of-a-number-using-its-prime-factorization/)

```
def generateDivisors(curIndex, curDivisor, arr): 
  " Yields the next factor based upon prime exponent " 
  if (curIndex == len(arr)): 
    yield curDivisor
    return

  for i in range(arr[curIndex][0] + 1): 
    yield from generateDivisors(curIndex + 1, curDivisor, arr) 
    curDivisor *= arr[curIndex][1]


def prime_factorization(n):
    " Generator for factors of n "

    # To store the prime factors along 
    # with their highest power 
    arr = [] 

    # Finding prime factorization of n 
    i = 2
    while(i * i <= n): 
      if (n % i == 0): 
        count = 0
        while (n % i == 0): 
          n //= i 
          count += 1
        
        # For every prime factor we are storing 
        # count of it's occurenceand itself. 
        arr.append([count, i])

      i += 2 if i % 2 else 1
    
    # If n is prime 
    if (n > 1): 
      arr.append([1, n]) 
    
    curIndex = 0
    curDivisor = 1
    
    # Generate all the divisors 
    yield from generateDivisors(curIndex, curDivisor, arr)
```

Method 4--Wheel Factorization

```
def wheel_factorization(n): 
    " Factors of n based upon getting primes for trial division based upon wheel factorization "

    # Init to 1 and number
    result = {1, n}

    # set up prime generator
    primes = prime_generator()   

    # Get next prime
    i = next(primes)

    while(i * i <= n): 
      if (n % i == 0):
        result.add(i)
        
        while (n % i == 0): 
          n //= i 
          result.add(n)

      i = next(primes)  # use next prime

    return result

def prime_generator():
  " Generator for primes using trial division and wheel method "
  yield 2; yield 3; yield 5; yield 7;

  def next_seq(r):
    " next in the equence of primes "
    f = next(r)
    yield f

    r = (n for n in r if n % f)  # Trial division
    yield from next_seq(r)

  def wheel():
    " cycles through numbers in wheel whl "
    whl = [2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 6, 2, 6, 4, 2,
          6, 4, 6, 8, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 8, 6, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6,
          2, 6, 6, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 10, 2, 10]
    
    while whl:
      for element in whl:
        yield element

  def wheel_accumulate(n, gen):
    " accumulate wheel numbers "
    yield n

    total = n
    for element in gen:
      total += element
      yield total

  for p in next_seq(wheel_accumulate(11, wheel())):
    yield p
```

**Test Code**

```
from timeit import timeit

cnt = 100000  # base number of repeats for timeit

print('{0: >12} {1: >9} {2: >9} {3: >9} {4: >9}'.format('N', 'Trial', 'Primes', 'Division', 'Wheel'))
for k in range(1, 31):
  N = 2**k
  count = cnt // k   # adjust repeats based upon size of k
  x = timeit(lambda:trial(N), number=count)
  y = timeit(lambda:sieve(N), number=count)
  z = timeit(lambda:list(prime_factorization(N)), number=count)
  k = timeit(lambda:list(wheel_factorization(N)), number=count)
  print(f"{N:12d} {1:9d} {x/y:9.5f} {x/z:9.5f} {x/k:9.5f}")
```

Comment: These methods are all applied to smallish values. For values near the upper bound of 2\*\*64 there are faster methods like Pollard-rho, SQUFOF, and deterministic ECM. At least they're alleged to be faster. They'd need to be added to your test to be sure. Typically a hybrid method is used, like first trial division or probably wheel based on your results up to some limit, and then switch to the more advanced method.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk--thanks for the feedback.  You're right that these probably outperform other methods only for smallish values (i.e. ~10^12 or so).  Additionally, looking at code for these other methods they also require additional libraries (i.e.  Pollard-rho requires random, etc. ) which violates  Poster's constraint of only using the math library.   Correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need random for Pollard-rho. The analysis of Pollard-Rho assumes randomness but actual implementations work fine without it.